# Can you change facebook app Id once it has been assigned?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Having some issues with my app due to a server change meaning the IP address has changed it seems that having a new IP address causes issues with the app ID. Is it possible to get a new app id for my app without having to create a new app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible. No chance.

Comment: Thanks, I have the issue where my server has changed that the app is hosted on. I think this change has caused issues with the appid/ip address. Any ideas on what the link is between the IP address and appid, and if there is any way of changing either?

Comment: There is no link between the app id and the ip adress. None at all. You should be able to solve your problem without switching to a new app. Double check your app settings (canvas url, site url, mobile web url, page tab url). Also in your advanced settings check the security settings (server white list).

Comment: Probably not the OP's problem, but you can whitelist IP addresses for API access using the app secret. If set, any IPs not on the whitelist won't be able to use the app secret for API access. You can change this under the Advanced section in your app settings.